# have a fair crack at all sorts

Tags: idioms

A young girl says that she's got skills of work as a barman from the previous jobs; she says that now she moved to work in Yorkshire; she's quite proficient and now she "**can have a fair crack at all sorts**".

What does it mean?

Source: this quote is from a book 'New Beginnings' by LimeyLady

Comment: It sounds like regional slang, as a variation on "fair chance" or "fair go".  "All sorts" is simply short for "all sorts of jobs".

Comment: Although you refer to the "skills of a barman" and not to her directly as a barman, you can use the gender-neutral **bartender** for both men and women.

Comment: Bartender-it's something new I've never met before. Thank you, Ronald!

Comment: @Nana Goshadze  This is a relatively common idiom in Australia. It is also often heard in this form, 'Fair crack of the whip', which is used to mean either, 'Treat everyone the same' or 'Give someone a break'.

Answer (score 2):

It means that she is willing to do a wide range of things. She may not be an expert but, from skills and experience gained in previous employment, she will probably be able to handle most things that are required of her.

Answer (score 2):

To **have a crack** at something is to have a chance or opportunity to do it.

> I can't get this frozen nut to budge.    The threads are rusty. We need to use some sort of solvent.
>   -- Let me have a crack at it.

To have a **fair** crack at something means to have a *a decent chance* of getting it or being able to do it.

> I have a fair crack at that promotion.
>
> I stand a decent chance of getting that promotion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sir! Sorry for doing that now, but as the English say: better late, than newer"-I am not very fluent in using English, or computers...anyway, I feel more confident today than 9 days ago when I put my question for the first time. People like you help others, like me, a lot to improve their English, and I am grateful to you for that. Regards
 Nana

Comment: You are certainly welcome :)